# javascript applying function to different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

What i want to achieve:

1. A function that calculates the average score of an array with scores.
2. Make the function re-usable for different arrays

Achieved so-far:

```js
const grades = [9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6];
function classAverage () {
    let sumOfGrades = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < (grades.length); i++) {
        sumOfGrades += grades[i];

    }
    const averageGrade = sumOfGrades/(grades.length);
    return averageGrade;
}
classAverage(grades);
console.log(averageGrade);
```

This seem to work in my ide, here it produces an error averageGrade not defined.
Next i'd like this function to be apply-able to more arrays like grades1999 or grades2021 but the for loop inside the function uses the grades array for calculation, how can i achieve that this function would work with something like: classAverage grades(2019) arrays with different names.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you never use the handed over array. instead you use the global `grades` array.

Comment: `const averageGrade` is declared inside the function, so it is only available inside this function. Also you are calling it with `classAverage(grades)`, you are passing it something (grades), but the function does not accept any argument, so this is useless.

Comment: also, you need to use the value *returned* by the function: `const average = classAverage(grades);`

Comment: You actually need two functions here `sum(array)` which returns the sum of an array and `avg(array)` which uses `sum` to compute the average. Neither function should use `class`, `grades` and other problem-specific terms.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions! This is really helping me to improve my skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method (`classAverage`) to the `Array.prototype` and then call it with different grade arrays.

```js
Array.prototype.classAverage = function () {
  return this.reduce((r, g) => r + g, 0) / (this.length || 1);
};

const grades = [9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6];
const grades1999 = [1, 8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3];
const grades2020 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const grades2023 = [];

console.log(grades.classAverage());
console.log(grades1999.classAverage());
console.log(grades2020.classAverage());
console.log(grades2023.classAverage());
```

Comment: What makes you think an average of an empty array is 0? It could be 42 just as well.

Comment: 1. Don't touch prototype. 2. Code otherwise [identical to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67091221/295783) posted half an hour earlier.

Answer (score 5):

You need a parameter for the array inside of the function to calculate different arrays.

As result, you need an assignment of the returned value or use it directly without storing the result.

Then you could take the values directly with a [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Some hints:

- By taking a property, you need not to wrap it in parentheses.
- For getting the difference of local or global scope, have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

```js
function classAverage (grades) {
    let sumOfGrades = 0;
    for(const grade of grades) {
        sumOfGrades += grade;
    }
    return sumOfGrades/grades.length;
}

console.log(classAverage([9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a few tweaks to what you have and it should run fine

```js
const gradesData = [9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6];

function classAverage(grades) {
  let sumOfGrades = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < (grades.length); i++) {
    sumOfGrades += grades[i];
  }

  const averageGrade = sumOfGrades / (grades.length);
  return averageGrade;
}

console.log(classAverage(gradesData));
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and added a console.log to see the result

Answer (score 2):

See other comments for why your code failed.

Reduce is made for this

```js
const numArrayAverage = arr => arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/arr.length;

console.log(numArrayAverage([9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6]));
```

With input testing

```js
const numArrayAverage = arr => Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 0 ?  arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/arr.length : "Invalid input";

console.log(numArrayAverage ([9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6]));
console.log(numArrayAverage ([]));
```

Comment: should be `.reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0)` to make it work with empty arrays

Comment: @georg Added a version with input testing

Comment: I'm not sure this is better. An average of an empty array is not 0.

Comment: Ok, changed to return invalid input and renamed the functions